# Error "ORA-0091:Invalid Character" when executing a PL-SQL statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, query, plsql, syntax

I'm new to oracle pl-sql and I'm facing error `ORA-0091:Invalid character` when executing this query below. But when I comment the `Execute Immediate` statement and use `dbms_output.put_line` the result of the variable `qry` is fine and there is no problem with the query inside `qry` variable.

```
declare
qry                  varchar2(5000);
effdate              date := to_date('5/19/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
user_id              varchar2(1000) := 'pantea';
search_number        varchar2(50)   := '8080';
deposit_filter_query varchar2(5000) := '  deposit_group_code =  -1
                                    and deposit_group_desc =  -1                                      
                                    and currency_desc      = ''-1''
                                    group by customer_num
                                    having sum(dep_avg_balance) > 1;';

begin

  qry := 'insert into dep_filter_cust
           select distinct customer_num ,''' || search_number || '''
              from vmi_customer_deposit_detail v
                inner join branchlf_user b
              on b.userid = ''' || user_id || '''
                and dep_branch_cod = v.dep_branch_cod
           where effective_date = to_date(''' ||
             to_char(effdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy') || ''','' mm/dd/yyyy'') and ' ||
              deposit_filter_query;

  --dbms_output.put_line(qry);
  execute immediate to_char(qry);
         commit;

 end;
```

I was wondering if you could help me finding the problem here . Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is teh purpose of `to_char`in the `execute immediate to_char(qry);` statement? What happens if you do a `dbms_output.put_line(to_char(qry));` instead of  `execute immediate to_char(qry);?

Comment: @miracle173 Even without the use of to_char() , I receive the same error

Comment: Why are you not using Bind variables?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql?

Comment: The "deposit_filter_query" part is different each time the statement is being executed. 
@MichaelKutz

Comment: The final purpose is to actually 'Execute' the query in the variable . Buy using dbms_outlut.put_line () , I just want to see my exact query .

Comment: I am not sure but I think qry should not end with a ';'

Comment: @miracle173 thank you . It was correct . Problem solved . the ; was extra . If you want you can post your answer so that I can chose it as the correct answer.

Comment: I 2nd what mirale173 said.  Also, use `DBMS_SQL` and Bind your variables instead.

Comment: @PanteaTourang fine. I have not time to post an answer. But  it is possible that you answer your own question.

Comment: @MichaelKutz could you please explain your suggestion a little bit more ? I mean using dbms_sql and binding variables . Could you give me an example? Cause I'm very very new to pl-sql. Thanks

Comment: remove the `;` from your SQL string

Comment: @PanteaTourang that is strange. I executed your statement now and it said: "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" (this is Oracle Database EE 12.1.0.2.0 )

Comment: @miracle173 . I'm working with Oracle 11-g and the problem solved after removing ';' from the end of "deposit_filter_query " in the 'Declare part' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your original problem is the unnecessary semicolon ( `;` ).

## Code Review

By building the query the way you did, you are introducing SQL Injection Vulnerability. (obligatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/327/) reference).  To prevent SQL Injections, use BIND variables.

Most RDBMS allow you to use `?` as a place holder.  Oracle supports this and Named place holders (eg `:SEARCH_NUM` ).  By using a Bind variable, DATE data type will be bound as DATEs, etc.  This removes the necessity for `TO_CHAR`/`TO_NUMBER`.

Since your code is really dynamic, I highly advise using the `DBMS_SQL` package to parse your SQL statement and Bind the variables.  This is especially true if the usage of Binds will be dynamic also. (eg use two variables one time, use 3 another, etc.)

Documentation for `DBMS_SQL` can be seen [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm).

Example code:

```sql
declare
  qry                  varchar2(5000);
  effdate              date := to_date('5/19/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
  user_id              varchar2(1000) := 'pantea';
  search_number        varchar2(50)   := '8080';
  deposit_filter_query varchar2(5000) := '  deposit_group_code =  -1
                                      and deposit_group_desc =  -1                                      
                                      and currency_desc      = ''-1''
                                      group by customer_num
                                      having sum(dep_avg_balance) > 1'; -- removed semi-colon
  initial_dml           varchar2(5000) := 'insert into dep_filter_cust (col1, col2)' || chr(10) -- alway define the columns in INSERT
             || 'select distinct customer_num , :SEARCH_NUM
                from vmi_customer_deposit_detail v
                  inner join branchlf_user b
                on b.userid = :USER_ID
                  and dep_branch_cod = v.dep_branch_cod
             where effective_date = :EFFDATE' || CHR(10); -- chr(10) === \n; NEWLINE character for visualisation

actual_sql  varchar2(32767);

c   pls_integer;
ret PLS_INTEGER;

begin

  -- build your SQL (I do this in a separate function)
  actual_sql := initial_dml || ' and ' || deposit_filter_query;

  -- debug results
  dbms_output.put_line( actual_sql );

  -- get your cursor
  c := dbms_sql.open_cursor();

  -- parse the SQL
  dbms_sql.parse( c, actual_sql, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE );

  -- bind variables (this can be dynamic if needed)
  -- Oracle can use NAMED Binds
  dbms_sql.bind_variable( c, ':SEARCH_NUM', search_number );
  dbms_sql.bind_variable( c, ':USER_ID', user_id );
  dbms_sql.bind_variable( c, ':EFFDATE', effdate );

  -- execute
  ret := dbms_sql.execute( c );

  -- close the cursor
  dbms_sql.close_cursor( c );
end;
/
```

If you don't do that, at the very least, use the `USING` clause of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

eg

```sql
execute immediate actual_sql using search_number, user_id, effdate;
```

Comment: Very informative . Thanks you . Did not consider 'injection'. Thanks.